# Translation issue for constraint Messages in symfony2

Tags: symfony, constraints, translation, validation

I followed this link http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translating-database-content to copy validators._my_locale_.xlf to my bundle, and cumstomized the translation, but it didn't work, I had set my locale like:

> translator:      { fallback: %locale% }

whatever I modified even made some wrong syntax, it happend nothing, I guess that the translator didn't point to my validators file, any ideas guys? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to clear the cache after you add a new translation resource.